# Trouble changing SSH port {

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to change ssh port with command "vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config".
The config is read only and I cannot change anything.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the file with superuser rights:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You will need to enter your user's password if prompted.